# How to use Jackson to serialize Scala value classes as strings?

Tags: json, scala, serialization, jackson

I want to use Scala's value classes (or a normal case class) to give stronger types to some strings in my program. When I serialize instances of these classes using Jackson I want them to be strings.

For example:

```
case class Brand(name: String) extends AnyVal
val brands = Seq(Brand("Coke"), Brand("Disney"))
val brandCount = Map(Brand("Coke") -> 5, Brand("Disney") -> 10)
```

Since `Brand` is just a wrapper for a String, I want the corresponding JSON serialization for these variables to be:

```
brands:     ["Coke", "Disney"]
brandCount: {"Coke": 5, "Disney": 10}
```

By default I get:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

println(mapper.writeValueAsString(brands))
// ==> [{"name":"Coke"},{"name":"Disney"}]
println(mapper.writeValueAsString(brandCount))
// ==> {"Brand(Coke)":5,"Brand(Disney)":10}
```

The best I could come up with is to define a custom serializer and key serializer for `Brand`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator

class BrandSerializer extends JsonSerializer[Brand] {
  override def serialize(
    b: Brand,
    json: JsonGenerator,
    provider: SerializerProvider
  ): Unit = {
    json.writeString(b.name)
  }
}

class BrandKeySerializer extends JsonSerializer[Brand] {
  override def serialize(
    b: Brand, 
    json: JsonGenerator,
    provider: SerializerProvider
  ): Unit = {
    json.writeFieldName(b.name)
  }
}

val serializers = new SimpleModule("Serializers");
serializers.addSerializer(classOf[Brand], new BrandSerializer())
serializers.addKeySerializer(classOf[Brand], new BrandKeySerializer());

val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
mapper.registerModule(serializers)

println(mapper.writeValueAsString(brands))
// ==> ["Coke","Disney"]
println(mapper.writeValueAsString(brandCount))
// ==> {"Coke":5,"Disney":10}
```

Is there a better (or less verbose) way to serialize these value classes (or any case class) as strings?

Comment: Is using jackson a requirement?

Comment: Yep, I'm using a framework which renders HTTP JSON responses using Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think, there is a way to make it do all you want, and nothing you don't want in one go ... 
The best thing you can do that comes to mind is replace `Brand` with `Product1`, and `b.name` with `b._1` (I also think, your key serializer is wrong - it should be writing out `b.getClass.getSimpleName`, not not `b.name`).

That wouldn't make it any less verbose for writing out a single class, but will at least eliminate the need to create a separate serializer for every type like that.

The downside, of course, is that *every* one-field case class will end up written this way, which may be more than what you wished for ..